# Client is trying to get data with Socket.io but doesn't seem to connect

Tags: node.js, sockets, reactjs, socket.io

I have set up sockets on my client and server, but I can't seem to get my data to come into my client. It seems they are connecting properly, I just can't get any data to come through. There are no error messages either.

Here is my server code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('custom-message', function () {
    console.log("Hitting messages socket");
    Message.find(function(err, messages){
      if(err){
        socket.emit('custom-message', err)
      } else {
        socket.emit('custom-message', messages);
      }
    })
  });

});
```

Here is the function in the client that connects to the socket:

```
  loadMessagesFromServer: function(){
    console.log("About to load messages")
    socket.on('custom-message', function(msg){
      console.log("connected in client", msg)
    });
  },
```

Like I said it is a pretty simple example, I just can't seem to get the data in `loadMessagesFromServer` .. And there are no erros, the only way I have been debugging is trying different things..

Answer (score 0):

You are listening on the event `messages`. So you need to emit the same event not `socket.emit('messages: err', err)`. Try with `socket.emit("messages", error)`. Moreover, in your server-side code, you need first to receive a `message` event and only then your socket will emit the messages. Remove the `socket.on(custom-messages)`. Why do you need it?

**Server-side code**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
/* Here a client connection is established. The on("connection") 
*  event will be triggered as many times as`io.connect("the-uri")`
*  is triggered (and succeeded) in the client`
*/

// Listening for the post event
   socket.on("post", function(messages){
       console.log("client posted data:", messages)       

      // Find messages and emit result
       Message.find(function(err, messages){
         if(err){
           socket.emit('error', err)
         } else {
           socket.emit("message", messages);
         }
       });

    });
});
```

**Client-side code**

```
registerOnMessageFromServerListener: function(){
    socket.on("message", function(msg){
    console.log("received message:", msg);
});

registerOnErrorFromServerListener: function(){
    socket.on("error", function(error){
    console.log("an error occured:", error);
});

registerOnMessageFromServerListener();
registerOnErrorFromServerListener();
socket.emit("post", "a-message");
```

Also make sure that you call the `loadMessagesFromServer` before you establish the socket connection

Comment: I implemented the changes. I have update the code above to reflect the new changes. How do I first have it receive a message? I have messages in the database, so I thought the Message.find() will go and get the messages, and than emit them?

Comment: Ok so that works .But now the `on connection` only supports getting messages. I was trying to set it up so I could have second function inside there that allows me to `POST` the message.. Can I not get this to work the way I have it above?

Comment: Basically I don't understand why your way works but the way above doesn't.  How would you create a `POST` socket without opening a second `io.on(connection)` ?

Comment: That is why I was trying to use `socket.on(custom-messages)`

Comment: @fresh5447 I've updated my answer. Hope that this answers your question